# DirectShow Pixels Are Out of Order When Capturing NTSC Analog Board

Tags: c++, video, directx, directshow, directx-11

I am writing a custom video rendering filter for Directshow.  My renderer assumes the incoming pixels are organized one row of pixels at a time (*correct assumption?*) and blits them to another DirectX display elsewhere using a DirectX texture.

This approach works with webcams as input, but when I use an analog capture board, the samples the renderer receives are not in any expected order (see left image below). When I render the capture using the stock DirectShow video renderer, it looks fine (see right image below). So the directshow renderer must be doing something extra that my renderer is not. Any idea what it is?

Some more details:

- The capture card is NTSC, I'm not sure if that would matter.
- As input to the custom renderer, I am accepting only `MEDIASUBTYPE_RGB24`, so I do not think that this is a YUV issue (is it?).
- It's a bit hard to see, but the second image below is my filter graph. My custom renderer connects to the color space converter on the far right.
- I assume that the pixels coming into my renderer, are all organized one row of pixels at a time. Is this a correct assumption?

[image: sample output]

[image: My Rendering Graph]

Comment: The picture suggests that pixel rows are incorrectly shifted one against another. It is a typical problem with using incorrect stride, but you don't show any relevant information to tell more about possible cause.

Comment: What information would you need? How do I determine the correct stride?

Comment: Full dump of media types on all connections would be great. You can get that using GraphStudioNext `Ctrl+T`, for example. Also you would want to get rid of excessive filters which might also interfere (even though I realize you have them because of interlaced content).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe texture is padded to keep rows aligned at (multiply of) 32 bytes per row? Mind you that I did not ever use DirectShow but that's what I would expect in D3D.
In other words, your input might have different stride than you think. Unfortunately I do not know DS so I can only assume that something that computes input / output coordinates should have different stride factor e.g. something in code that looks like this `offset = y * stride + x`.

Comment: You nailed it. The reason why the webcam worked was because it was 1280 pixels wide... divisible by 32. The capture device was 720 pixels wide, and not divisible by 32. Thank you!